# Web frontend for a Python application

Tags: python

I created a nice RSS application in Python.  It took a while and most of the code just does heavy work, like formatting XML, downloading feeds, etc. To the application itself requires very little user interaction, just a initial list of RSS feeds and some parameters.

What would be really nice, is if I was able to have a web front-end which allowed me to have the user edit their feeds and parameters, then they could click a create button and it runs.

I don't really want to have to rewrite the thing in a web framework. Is there anything that will allow me to build a nice front-end allowing it to interact with the normal Python underneath?

Comment: "Is there anything that will allow me to build a nice front-end allowing it to interact with the normal Python underneath?" I was under the impression that this is indeed the purpose of pretty much every python web framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[web.py](http://webpy.org) is a very lightweight 'library' (not framework) that you can put as a front end to your app. Just `import` your app within the main controller and use it as you would.

The Python standard library also includes a builting `SimpleHTTPServer` module which might be what you need to create a front end for your app.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on your needs, free time, etc.

I recommend two solutions:

- [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) - a very rich framework which allows you to create full featured sites using only accessible components (in most cases they are good enough)
- http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/ - collections of tools if you want to have possibility to control everything from the low level

Answer (score 0):

You may also either deploy your **Python code as CGI script** on a webserver of your choice, e.g. [Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/cgi-howto.html):

> The CGI (Common Gateway Interface) defines a way for a web server to
>   interact with external content-generating programs, which are often
>   referred to as CGI programs or CGI scripts.

According to a [Qura-question](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-run-Java-and-Python-in-Tomcat) this might be appropriate only for small projects, but I do not say anything wrong with that since it worked well for me for perl-scripts. The same source suggests a **Python WSGI (web-service gateway)** service like [uwsgi](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/uwsgi/) another service dedicated to running Python code.

Last but not least, there is the solution to **encapsulate your Python into Java-code**: I stumbled upon the Quora-question ["How do I run Java and Python in Tomcat?"](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-run-Java-and-Python-in-Tomcat) which refered to using [Jython](http://Jython) and plyJy, the latter project is not alive anymore. However, there is also a related question [on the topic of bundling Python and Java.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921809/bundling-python-pyfiles-along-with-java-class-files-for-a-web-application).